# Javascript Regex - select one item out a long string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string that I'm trying to get one item which is the Stock#, if I could get it another way I could, but I'm stuck with:

Ingot Silver Metallic Exterior, Charcoal Black / Silver Stitch Interior, Status: Dealer Ordered, Engine: Regular Unleaded I-4 1.6 L/97, Trans: Automatic, Stock#: IP-2758P4B, VIN #: 3FADP4BJ2FM114457

So basically I just need IP-2758P4B.
I've been trying different things from different answers from StackOverflow another place, but no luck.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you split the string based on the COMMA and look at that index?

Comment: A negative already? tough crowd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below code,

```
> var foo = "Ingot Silver Metallic Exterior, Charcoal Black / Silver Stitch Interior, Status: Dealer Ordered, Engine: Regular Unleaded I-4 1.6 L/97, Trans: Automatic, Stock#: IP-2758P4B, VIN #: 3FADP4BJ2FM114457";
undefined
> var re = /Stock#:\s*([^,]*)/g;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(foo)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }
IP-2758P4B
```

Answer (score 1):

Split is often easier to use than regular expressions:

Here is how I'd solve it.

```
var a = "Ingot Silver Metallic Exterior, Charcoal Black / Silver Stitch Interior, Status: Dealer Ordered, Engine: Regular Unleaded I-4 1.6 L/97, Trans: Automatic, Stock#: IP-2758P4B, VIN #: 3FADP4BJ2FM114457";

var stockNum = a.split("Stock#:")[1].split(",")[0].trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stock#: (\S+)
```

See Demo.It captures non space characters after Stock.

http://regex101.com/r/mU9cF1/1

Answer (score 0):

Regex in JavaScript is rather simple, but I really suggest you read a tutorial - there are tonnes on Google.

As for solving the problem with regex:

```
var a = "Ingot Silver Metallic Exterior, Charcoal Black / Silver Stitch Interior, Status: Dealer Ordered, Engine: Regular Unleaded I-4 1.6 L/97, Trans: Automatic, Stock#: IP-2758P4B, VIN #: 3FADP4BJ2FM114457";
var regex = /Stock#: (.+?),/g;
var resultArray = regex.exec(a);
if (resultArray.length >= 1) {
  var result = resultArray[1];
} else {
  // The stock number couldn't be found
}
```

Comment: Be very careful when you assume an array will exist.

Comment: Very true. I modified the answer to reflect that.